# Log4Net Config setup error : No appender named [FileAppender] could be found

Tags: log4net, app-config

I have created a lognet library using .Net Core 6.0.

The library class has the following initialization.

```
public static class MyLogger
{
    private static readonly ILog logger = LogManager.GetLogger("");

    static MyLogger()
    {
        log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure();
    }
}
```

In my console application's app.config has the following settings,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler,log4net" />
    </configSections>

 <log4net>
    <appender name="RollingFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
        <file value="C:\\Logs\\Test.log" />
        <appendToFile value="true" />
        <rollingStyle value="Size" />
        <maxSizeRollBackups value="5" />
        <maximumFileSize value="10MB" />
        <staticLogFileName value="true" />

        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
            <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %level %logger - %message%newline" />
        </layout>
    </appender>

    <appender name="ConsoleAppender" type="log4net.Appender.ConsoleAppender" >
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
            <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger - %message%newline" />
        </layout>
    </appender>
    <root>
        <level value="Info" />
        <level value="Warn" />
    <appender-ref ref="FileAppender" />
    
    </root>
 </log4net>
</configuration>
```

I research didn't help me to resolve the issue. Thanks for your help.

Comment: That's correct, the error is gone, but its not creating the file>@mxmissile

Comment: I want to accept your solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your root config to use an existing appender:

```
 <appender-ref ref="RollingFileAppender" />
```